Creating All pass filter directly in the frequency domain
I have a very particular problem for my research: I need to create two all pass filters, with very similar but not completely equal frequency (phase) responses. To do this I have created an allpass filter by the conventional method of zeros and poles positioning (around 200 of each); this is the first filter, which is causal and behaves as expected when applied over a signal (the application consists in multiplying the filter and the tapered signal in the frequency domain, and then reversing the result to the time domain). To create the second filter I add perturbations to the phase of the frequency response of the first filter, always making sure that the group delay remains positive, so the causality of the second filter is not broken, and that the phase remains a continuous function. However, when applying the second filter I have discovered that the causality has been broken, and that at certain frequencies the filtered signal "appears" before the original signal. This, despite the fact that the phase is negative, and that the phase delay and the group delay are positive for all the frequencies.
I suspect (I may be mistaken) that the problem with the second filter is related to the reason why all-pass filters are not designed in the frequency domain: However, I have been searching for a more precise/mathematical reason, but unfortunately I have only found generic responses saying that the frequency design of an all pass filter can produce problems with causality and the numerical stability.
So my question is simple: apart from the group delay, what other exact measurement could I take while designing the frequency response of the second filter (which could considered as designed in the frequency domain) to ensure that it is a causal filter. And more generally speaking, if designing an allpass filter in the frequency domain directly with the phase were absolutely necessary, is it not enough to ensure that the group delay is always positive to know that the produced filter will be causal? What other criteria exists that may inform about this property of the filter?
(As for my problem, although an apparent possible solution may be to introduce the fluctuations in the zeros/poles properties, for reasons not mentioned here the fluctuations have to be introduced directly over the phase of the filter)
Thanks!
Edit: Indeed! as Dan explained, the key are the KK relations. I have enforced them in the frequency domain and the causality has been recovered (although by a different method that the one proposed by Dan). I'm a bit surprised by the fact that negative group delays don't necessarily break causality, or that positive group delay of phase delays don't imply causality neither as I thought the group delay was related with the energy... I'll have to check this in depth later. For now, the KK relations provide me with what I need. Thanks!

so, if the group delay is positive for all frequencies, it's positive, and that's a mathematical fact. Maybe you're getting into trouble because you implement your frequency-domain filtering in a way that makes the convolution be circular?

I have been searching up and down, and I have found absolutely no problem with the implementation part. What makes me suspect there is a deeper/theoretical reason behind my problem is this: if the only criteria for creating causal filters is having positive group delays, why allpass filters are not then implemented creating a frequency response by multiplying a constant magnitude (1) and a desired phase function($\phi$ with $-d\phi/d\omega>0$) as $h=1*e^{i\phi}$? This would be much more simple that all the existing theory of poles/zeros, right?

the answer to that lies in the fact that filter design purely in the frequency domain suffers from problems caused by inherent or explicit windowing and interpolation properties that are hard to "see" in that domain. Can you try this: I don't know how long your filter is, but say it's N taps long. Can you try and add N/2 zeros before and N/2 zeros after in time domain or, conversely add one zero in between each current tap (in frequency domain) and apply the same methodology to this new 2N sized filter? You also really should write down explicitly how you do your "filter application", I

quite honestly don't trust it :)

You can have negative group delay over portions of your frequency response and still be causal. I’m not sure if that was understood?

As the OP has already found, stability (and true causality) is not guaranteed when finding IIR filter solutions. As for additional steps that can be taken, this is often an iterative approach where a linear phase term is added to the desired phase response prior to processing for the filter solution (such as the inverse FFT approach as the OP is doing here, or MattL's least squares approach I link further below).
To be causal, the filter response must meet the Kramers-Kronig relations. The Kramers-Krong relations state that for a causal, stable filter, the real part and imaginary part of the complex frequency response will be related by the Hilbert Transform. If the resulting response was not causal, it is likely due to the target response violating Kramers-Kronig, which is resolved by adding the linear phase term. The linear phase term adds an overall fixed delay while still providing the desired group delay variation (as the purpose of the all-pass filter). Please refer to DSP.SE #28381 for further details on the KK relations.
(I edited the following paragraph for clarity based on MattL’s comment)
In case it wasn't understood, having negative group delay is not a violation of causality in general (and therefore ensuring that group delay is always positive, meaning the slope of phase with respect to frequency is always negative, may not be a valid approach to ensure the solution is causal). (However as MattL explained in the comments, it is guaranteed to be positive for the case of all-pass filters.) Please see this existing post linked below where I have provided an example as well as detailed explanation as to how this occurs:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/66593/21048
As for alternate approaches to designing the filter, Mathias Lang (MattL who is active here and may post additional details when he's not on tour performing for concerts) has elaborated on an efficient and optimum least squares approach for all pass filter design at his blog post linked below:
https://mattsdsp.blogspot.com/2022/10/design-of-iir-allpass-filters-least.html

Thx for linking to my post on allpass filter design! Just one remark about group delay: you're of course completely right when you say that in general, causality does not imply non-negative group delay. However, in the special case of allpass filters this is indeed the case: the group delay of a causal allpass filter is necessarily non-negative.

@Matt Thanks Matt- that makes sense (and I updated my answer to reflect that). However I am not answering why the OP doesn’t succeed after placing that constraint. You may have further insight to that and if so would make for a great addition as another answer

Thank you for your responses! So, this means that I can actually design any causal allpass filter directly as $h=1*e^{i \phi}$ as long as $-d \phi/d \omega > 0$? Again, if this were the case, shouldn't this be the preferred method of allpass filters design instead of all the poles/zeros theory? I must remark also the causality was only recovered after I enforced the KK relations (which makes difficult this direct-design method). (Also, do you know of any book where KK relations are discussed in the context of digital filters? thanks!)

@Tojur I would suggest asking that as a separate and concise question to attract more answers and link this one.
